# Eclipse Periodic Save Error

Tags: eclipse

While using Eclipse I am encountering this error every few minutes.

An internal error occurred during: "Periodic workspace save.".
Cannot set lower sequence number for root (previous: 56, new: 55). Location: G:\Dropbox\Dawson\Semester 5\Eclipse Projects.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.safetable\org.eclipse.core.resources

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Is it possible to move your workspace out of DropBox? I saw a bug report on this https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=415014 and that user also was using DropBox.

Comment: Not really. I need to use Dropbox as my repository because I'm running Eclipse and my projects on many different computers.

Comment: Since it happens every couple of minutes maybe you could do it as a troubleshooting measure just to verify it's a DropBox->Eclipse interaction problem. If the problem goes away with the workspace outside of DropBox you might try GoogleDrive. You could also consider using an actual SCM tool like Mercurial. There are eclipse plug-ins for it, and free services like BitBucket that will handle the online portion.You will need to remember to both check in and then sync to bit bucket.

Comment: Eclipse bug 415014 mentioned above is marked fixed and available in the 4.4M2 build

Answer (score 1):

Go to G:\Dropbox\Dawson\Semester5\EclipseProjects.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.safetable and delete the existing file.

Or

Simply delete the .metadata folder. And restart Eclipse. This should resolve the error.